# Why does PageBreakAbove / PageBreakBelow not work here?

Tags: bugs, export, notebooks, formatting, document-creation

**Bug introduced in 12.0 or earlier and persisting through 12.1**

---

Create a notebook having interspersed cells of figures and text:

```
Do[
 CellPrint@TextCell[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}], "Text"];
 CellPrint@TextCell[ToString[i], "Text"],
 {i, 20}
]
```

Now save it as PDF. If you use the same paper size as me, there will be a page break after the cell containing `3`. Edit the cell and add `PageBreakBelow -> False`. Alternatively, edit the next cell and add `PageBreakAbove -> False`. This can be done with the Option Inspector.

But the page will still be broken at that point.

Page breaks can also be visualized without printing, by setting `ShowPageBreaks -> True` on the notebook and setting the Printout environment.

Why does Mathematica not respect page break instructions? How can I force it to not break the page between these two cells?

---

What I wanted was to create a figure caption cell style that stays together with the figure above, but I can't even get the page break options to work reliably when set explicitly on a cell, not to mention when included in a style.

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2

I've send a bug report to the official support on this issue: [CASE:4409941]. Just in case, I reproduce it here:

> The goal is to prevent addition of page breaks between the Caption
>   cells with numbers and the next cells.
>
> According to the Documentation, it should be possible to achieve this
>   simply by adding `PageBreakBelow->False` to the Caption cells, but it
>   doesn't work. Even in the case of grouped cells and with option
>   `GroupPageBreakWithin->False` it doesn't work. Addition of
>   `PageBreakAbove->False` to the next cells also doesn't change anything.
>
> Unexpectedly, addition of `PageBreakWithin->False` gives the desired
>   result, in full contradiction with the documented meaning of this
>   option and with undesired effect associated with its *documented*
>   meaning.
>
> The code below demonstrates the problem: pay attention to the bottom
>   of each imported page: the Caption cell number 6 at the bottom is
>   separated from the next cell containing "line"s by the page break in
>   the case of `nb[2]` despite the fact that  every of the used options
>   should prevent this according to the Documentation:
>   `PageBreakBelow->False` and `GroupPageBreakWithin->False` and
>   `PageBreakAbove->False`. But none of them works, as well as all them
>   together! The case of `nb[3]` demonstrates the expected behavior for
>   `nb[2]`: the caption cell number 6 is on the page 2 with the next cell -
>   but it is achieved by using the option `PageBreakWithin->False` which
>   shouldn't behave like this, according to the Documentation!
>
> ```
> ClearAll["Global`"];
> $Version
> (* The default state *)
> nb[1] = CreateDocument[
>    Flatten@Table[{TextCell["Caption" <> ToString[i], "Section", "Text"], 
>       TextCell[Column[Table[line, {9}], Center, 0.07], "Text"]}, {i, 20}], 
>       ShowPageBreaks -> True, WindowSelected -> False];
> (* An attempt to use PageBreakBelow->False and 
> GroupPageBreakWithin->False and PageBreakAbove->False: failure. 
> Try to use them separately and/or without grouping (remove "Section" style)
> - it also fails in the all cases! *)
> nb[2] = CreateDocument[
>    Flatten@Table[{TextCell["Caption" <> ToString[i], "Section", 
>        "Text", PageBreakBelow -> False, GroupPageBreakWithin -> False], 
>       TextCell[Column[Table[line, {9}], Center, 0.07], "Text", 
>        PageBreakAbove -> False]}, {i, 20}], ShowPageBreaks -> True, 
>    WindowSelected -> False];
> (* An attempt to use PageBreakWithin->False: works, but why? It 
> shouldn't work in the sense of GroupPageBreakWithin->False! *)
> nb[3] = CreateDocument[
>    Flatten@Table[{TextCell["Caption" <> ToString[i], "Section", "Text"], 
>       TextCell[Column[Table[line, {9}], Center, 0.07], "Text"]}, {i, 20}], 
>       PageBreakWithin -> False, ShowPageBreaks -> True, WindowSelected -> False];
> Row[Row /* Panel /@ 
>   Table[Show[#, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 500},  PlotRange -> Automatic] & /@ 
>     ImportString[ExportString[nb[i], "PDF"]][[;; 2]], {i, 3}]]
> Do[NotebookClose[nb[i]], {i, 3}]
> ```
>
> > [image: output]

---

### Update

I have checked and found that `GroupPageBreakWithin -> False` options is ignored too, both for `CellGrouping -> Automatic` and `CellGrouping -> Manual`. Here are corresponding pieces of code:

```
DocumentNotebook[
 Flatten@Table[{TextCell[ToString[i], "Section", 
     GroupPageBreakWithin -> False], 
    ExpressionCell[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}], "Text", 
     GroupPageBreakWithin -> False]}, {i, 20}], 
 GroupPageBreakWithin -> False]

DocumentNotebook[
 Table[CellGroup[{TextCell[ToString[i], "Section", 
     GroupPageBreakWithin -> False], 
    ExpressionCell[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}], "Text", 
     GroupPageBreakWithin -> False]}], {i, 20}], 
 CellGrouping -> Manual, GroupPageBreakWithin -> False]
```

In both cases the first break comes after "4", in full contradiction with the Documentation for `GroupPageBreakWithin`. Definitely a bug.

---

### Original answer

I confirm the problem with versions 12.0 and 12.1 on Windows 10 x64: both `File ► Save As... ► PDF Document (*.pdf)` and actual printing to a PDF printer don't respect the `PageBreakBelow -> False` and `PageBreakAbove -> False` settings. The same is true for the `Export` function:

```
Export["test.pdf", EvaluationNotebook[]] // SystemOpen
```

> [image: screenshot]

Worth reporting as a bug.

I also noticed that the `File ► Print Preview...` mode is very unstable and buggy: sometimes it visualizes the page breaks with `ShowPageBreaks -> True`, sometimes not, and even worse: this behavior and positions of the page breaks change with changing the `Magnification`. Here are screenshots of the same page (generated as described in the OP) in the "Print Preview" mode with `ShowPageBreaks -> True` set, but with different magnifications (the cursor is placed right after the cell containing "3" in the all cases):

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

[image: screenshot3]

[image: screenshot4]

[image: screenshot5]

Notice how "3" and the insertion point indicator are rendered *after* the page break at magnifications 50% and 75% (also notice that the break itself is rendered differently as compared to other magnifications) and how the page break isn't shown at magnification 150%. The page break also disappears after resizing the window by mouse...

Comment: I was able to get it working when I set `PageBreakWithin -> False` on the figure cell and `PageBreakBelow -> False` on the cell containing `3`. This works. But it's inconvenient as I was hoping to be able to have a cell which always stays attach to the cell above (or below), without having to also modify the cell above (or below). I wanted to do this to create figure captions.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you, the combination of **`PageBreakWithin -> False`** for the figure cell and `PageBreakBelow -> False` on the cell containing 3 works. Good to know that there is a way to control page breaking at all! May be it is also worth to try other combinations: `GroupPageBreakWithin -> False` for the cell with 3 (and auto-group it with next cell) and `PageBreakWithin -> False` for all cells with graphics, don't know whether it fits your needs.